# Write to file with xp_cmdshell in UTF-8

Tags: file, sql-server-2005, utf-8, xp-cmdshell

I am creating files with xp_cmdshell like this:

```
SELECT @command = 'echo ' + @fileContent + ' > e:\out\' + @fileName + '.csv'
exec master.dbo.xp_cmdshell 'mkdir "e:\out\"'
exec master..xp_cmdshell @command
```

The problem is that the file contents is not in UTF-8 and so some special characters are wrong.

Can i create the file in UTF-8 encoding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [SQLCMD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) instead the old tecnique as DOS outupt redirect

```
sqlcmd -S ServerName -d DataBaseName -E -o "CSV File Path & Location" -Q "Your Query" -W -w 4000 -s ";" -f 65001
```

the switch **-f 65001** indicate to use UTF8 as outfile file

```
SELECT @command = 'sqlcmd -S ServerName -d DataBaseName -E -o "'+ @fileName +'" -Q "Your  Query" -W -w 4000 -s ";" -f 65001'
exec master.dbo.xp_cmdshell 'mkdir "e:\out\"'
exec master..xp_cmdshell @command
```

p.s. i cant test it so please check the SQLCMD documentation

Hope it help

Answer (score 4):

I finally succeeded doing this by writing the output to a temp.txt file and adding the next PowerShell command to convert it to UTF-8:

```
-- Change encoding to UTF-8 with PowerShell 
SET @command = 'powershell -Command "Get-Content '+@Path+'\temp.txt -Encoding Unicode | Set-Content -Encoding UTF8 '+@path+'\'+@filename+'"';
EXEC xp_cmdshell @command;
```

Answer (score 0):

I chose Jan Lenders's way but did not use that encoding type setting when reading the time.

```
SET @COMMAND = 'powershell -Command "Get-Content '+ @PATH + @V_FILE_NAME + ' | Set-Content -Encoding UTF8 '+ @PATH + @V_FILE_NAME +'2"';
```

This is worked.

Thank you^^